# Variables from firebase in nodemailer inside cloudfunctions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer in firebase cloudfunctions to send emails to users on multiple  triggers.

Basically it works, the one thing I can't get my head around is the following: my Super Admin is allowed to write new mail templates, which are saved to a firebase database as a string. So let's say for example it contains a title as a string like this:

```
"Welcome to my App ${status.userData.name}!"
```

than in my cloud functions, when a trigger happens I'm getting one of those created templates like this:

Status is the object from the trigger db query:

```
exports.sendApplication = functions.database.ref('/xx/{userId}/').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  let status = change.after.val();
....

let messageRef = admin.database().ref('users').child('admin').child('template').child('welcome');
messageRef.once('value', snap => {
  let msg = snap.val();
  console.log('message: ', msg);
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${status.userData.email}`,
    to: `${status.userData.email}`,
    subject: `${msg.title}` 
    html: `
      <h1>${msg.title}</h1>
      ${msg.message}
    `....
```

console.log of msg.title gives me this:

```
"Welcome to my App ${status.userData.name}!"
```

console.log of status.userData.name gives me

```
"prename surname"
```

The problem is, in the E-Mail I get it's still `${status.userData.name}`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: whats is status?

Comment: If status doesn't have a value, it won't get interpolated into strings.  FYI, you don't need string interpolation if the only thing in the string is a variable.  Instead of ``${status.userData.email}`` you can just say `status.userData.email`.

Comment: status is the database object from the trigger, which is not empty, 
for example status.userData.email would be a string, that contains the users mailadress- e.g. test@rest.com

clarified that in the question too

Comment: I tried your suggestion now, still same issue: 

${msg.title} or ' + msg.title + '... give the same output in the sent mail: 
which is the string of msg.title (which contains variables i want to display in the mail)

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles uppon this: 
Solution is actually pretty easy:

as the Variable ${msg.title} contains variables inside a string i just had to replace the variable in the string with the actual variable like @Doug Stevenson suggested kind of:

```
msg.title = msg.title.replace("${status.userData.email}", status.userData.email);
```